# Unseparable element becomes separable

Tags: field-theory, separable-extension

Let $L/K$ be an extension of fields. Denote by $p$ the characteristic of $K$. One assumes that $p$ is a a prime. Let $a\in L$ not separable over $K$.  Does it exist an integer $s$ such $a^{p^s}$ is separable over $K$ and $[K(a^{p^s}):K]<p$?

Comment: When you write “$K/L$” (pronounced “$K$ over $L$”) the usual interpretation is that $K$ is an extension of $L$. It appears you want $L$ to be an extension of $K$, though…

Comment: My bad... I edit my post.

Comment: Say $K$ is the field of three elements and $a=\root4\of2$. It seems to me that $a^{3^s}$ is always of degree four over $K$.